# Can cleaning and volume operations in a HDD traced back?

Tags: windows

In Windows environment, Is it possible to trace back HDD operations like wiping, formatting, re-allocating, label changing etc., with timestamps?

Comment: There is a mismatch between the title and the content of the question. While the title asks for *all* operations (which includes any reads and writes) the question only asks for *specific* operations. Also, the tag indicates that you are asking for tracing in a specific environment, i.e. windows, so you should specify this in the question too.

Comment: Corrected as advised.

Comment: It sounds like you are asking what the Windows OS logs in terms of HDD operations. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes and also I'd like to know if such kind of log information stored in somewhere in HDD. For example, If I receive an external USB HDD used by another individual, can I reveal that It's recently wiped, erased or re-allocated?

Comment: I'd consider engaging a forensic analyst if you have concerns about a particular drive. There are special tools and training that can help determine certain events and if there is recoverable data on the drive in uninitialized/slack space etc.

Comment: @eetoneth To find out what Windows logs, look at the lists of event IDs (many lists available online). What is logged by a particular piece of hardware is up to the individual products and vendors. But, this is not something that would be logged (no value in keeping that data somewhere on the drive).